# Mouth detection using openCv returns a lot of circles in only one face

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCv with android studio to detect faces in an image along with the eyes and the mouth in each face. But, the problem is whenever I try to detect the mouth it returns multiple circles in a face which is wrong.

Here is the code I added for mouth detection:

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
...
InputStream iserM = getResources().openRawResource(
                                R.raw.haarcascade_mcs_mouth);
                        File cascadeDirERM = getDir("cascadeERM",
                                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        File cascadeFileERM = new File(cascadeDirERM,
                                "haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml");
                        FileOutputStream oserM = new FileOutputStream(cascadeFileERM);

                        byte[] bufferERM = new byte[4096];
                        int bytesReadERM;
                        while ((bytesReadERM = iserM.read(bufferERM)) != -1) {
                            oserM.write(bufferERM, 0, bytesReadERM);
                        }
                        iserM.close();
                        oserM.close();
...
//here begins
                        mJavaDetectorMouth = new CascadeClassifier(
                                cascadeFileERM.getAbsolutePath());
                        if (mJavaDetectorMouth.empty()) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load cascade classifier");
                            mJavaDetectorMouth = null;
                        } else
                            Log.i(TAG, "Loaded cascade classifier from "
                                    + mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        //here ends
...
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
...
Rect r = facesArray[i];
            MatOfRect mouths = new MatOfRect();
            Mat faceROI = mRgba.submat(facesArray[i]);
            mJavaDetectorMouth.detectMultiScale(faceROI, mouths,1.1,1,1, new org.opencv.core.Size(30, 30), new org.opencv.core.Size());
            Rect[] mouthArray = mouths.toArray();

            for (int j = 0; j < mouthArray.length; j++){
                Point center1 = new Point(facesArray[i].x + mouthArray[j].x + mouthArray[j].width * 0.5,
                        facesArray[i].y + mouthArray[j].y + mouthArray[j].height * 0.5);
                int radius = (int) Math.round(mouthArray[j].width / 2);
                Imgproc.circle(mRgba, center1, radius, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4, 8, 0);
            }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking around since I posted the question and tried a lot of things. But finally I found the solution: 
I changed:

```
 mJavaDetectorMouth.detectMultiScale(faceROI, mouths,1.1,1,1, new org.opencv.core.Size(30, 30), new org.opencv.core.Size());
```

To:

```
 mJavaDetectorMouth.detectMultiScale(faceROI, mouths,1.1, 2,
                    Objdetect.CASCADE_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
                            | Objdetect.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, new org.opencv.core.Size(30, 30), new org.opencv.core.Size());
```

and I solved the issue.

Comment: In my case the length of mouthArray is 0 .for picture taken by camera . Why ?